# Order Topology on $\mathbb{Z_+}$

Tags: general-topology, order-topology

Why is the order topology on $\mathbb{Z_+}$ a discrete one? I understand that the discrete topology will have all subsets of $\mathbb{Z_+}$ which means that all subsets of $\mathbb{Z_+}$ are open which is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you say not every subset is open? Every subset *is* open!

All the singletons $\{ n \}$ are basic open sets in the order topology, because
$$\begin{alignat}{2}
\{ 1 \} &\; = \{ x \in \mathbb{Z}_+ : x < 2 \} &\ &= (-\infty, 2)\\
\{ n+1 \} &\; = \{ x \in \mathbb{Z}_+ : n < x < n+2 \} &&= (n, n+2)
\end{alignat}$$
But open sets needn't all be *basic* open sets: in particular, any unions of basic open sets is open.

Any subset $X \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_+$ can be written as the union of singletons:
$$X = \bigcup_{n \in X} \{ n \}$$
...and so all subsets are open.

Comment: If we consider subset $X=(3,5]$, this is neither open nor closed.

Comment: Wut? $(3,5] = \{ 4, 5 \} = (3,6)$, so it's basic open. Which part of my answer do you disagree with? Once you have that singletons are open, you're done.

Comment: I am just trying to understand why $\{1\}$ would be open because there will be no open neighborhood to the "left of 1"

Comment: There doesn't need to be anything to the left. Sets of the form $(-\infty, n)$ are open in the order topology, and in $\mathbb{Z}^+$ we have $(-\infty, 2) = \{ 1 \}$. I'll update the notation in my post.